# How can I run a .NET Web API in a container?

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker, swagger, .net-6.0

How can I run a .NET Web API in a container?

Here is what I did:

1 Created a `foo` folder.

2 Inside the folder I opened a terminal and run the command `dotnet new webapi`. Then I run the `dotnet run` and verified that the swagger is accessible through browser.

3 Added the `Dockerfile` to the `foo` folder:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY ./ ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "foo.dll"]
```

[image]

4 Executed the `docker build -t aspnetapp .` command.

5 Went to `Properties/launchSettings.json` and found the value for the `profiles.foo.applicationUrl` (I used the value to verify that the app works by accessing swagger through browser in 2). The value is `https://localhost:7055;http://localhost:5062`:

[image]

6 Executed the `docker run -d -p 8080:7055` command.

7 Now I go to browser to the `https://localhost:8080/swagger` and expect to see the swagger page, but I see nothing:

[image]

What else I tried to do:

- in 6 I tried changing the command to `docker run -d -p 8080:5062`
- I checked the console for the started app and for some reasons it is referring to the 80th port:

```
{"EventId":14,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","Message":"Now listening on: http://[::]:80","State":{"Message":"Now listening on: http://[::]:80","address":"http://[::]:80","{OriginalFormat}":"Now listening on: {address}"}}

{"EventId":0,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","Message":"Application started. Press Ctrl\u002BC to shut down.","State":{"Message":"Application started. Press Ctrl\u002BC to shut down.","{OriginalFormat}":"Application started. Press Ctrl\u002BC to shut down."}}

{"EventId":0,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","Message":"Hosting environment: Production","State":{"Message":"Hosting environment: Production","envName":"Production","{OriginalFormat}":"Hosting environment: {envName}"}}

{"EventId":0,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","Message":"Content root path: /app/","State":{"Message":"Content root path: /app/","contentRoot":"/app/","{OriginalFormat}":"Content root path: {contentRoot}"}}
```

[image]

How can I make the app running in the container be accessible through my browser? I.e. how can I see the swagger and call the endpoint through browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your docker log information, `"Message":"Now listening on: http://[::]:80"` your web application exposes port is `80` from the container.

so I think you can try to map with that.

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80
```

we can use the below ways to change using port by [Endpoint configuration](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/fundamentals/servers/kestrel.md#endpoint-configuration), otherwise it might use default port.

- `ASPNETCORE_URLS` environment variable.
- `--urls` command-line argument.
- urls host configuration key.
- UseUrls extension method.

Comment: Mapping to the 80th posrt and changing the `https://localhost:8080/weatherforecast` to `http://localhost:8080/weatherforecast` solved the issue. Also, the swagger was not working because it is disabled in the Release configuration (I caught it by manually buillding and running the app completely without Docker).